# android things UART cannot receive data (RPi3B)

Tags: android, android-things

I tried the android things UART loopback sample project on github with my RPi3B.
https://github.com/androidthings/sample-uartloopback

When I send data from serial port debug tools on computer, the apps UART callback function are called but the UART read function cannot read the data, the following while function is never entered and the parameter read is always zero.

```
while ((read = mLoopbackDevice.read(buffer, buffer.length)) > 0) {
      mLoopbackDevice.write(buffer, read);
}
```

I have tried the mLoopbackDevice.write() function singly and that worked well.

I also have tried the mLoopbackDevice.read() function singly, that still didn't  receive any data, but I found my serial port debug tools always received the data what I sent. It seemed like the data was returned by linux system and cannot be received by androidthings system.

I have already removed console=serial0,115200 in cmdline.txt to close the console.

How can I solve it? Thank you!

Comment: Are you running Developer Preview 2? If so, I suggest you read this bug report as it might be affecting you as well: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=233938

Comment: Thank you Devunwired! It's working well now!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to turn off all flow control when config UART.
The wire connect should be  tx->rx, and rx->tx.